# Q : Let $f : \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ such that, for all $x,y\in\mathbb Z:$ $f(f(x) − y) = f(y) − f(f(x)).$ Show $f$ is bounded.

Tags: functional-equations, periodic-functions, bounded-variation

I came to the conclusion that f is periodic with period |f(x0)| for x0 non-zero. But I don't see how the periodicity in domain translates to a bound in the codomain. It probably has something to do with the fact that the image intervenes with the periodicity, but I can't put my hand precisely on it and the solution doesn't provide this explanation.

Can someone please explain this part to me? Thank you!

What I have until now :
By substituting $y = f(x)$ we obtain $f(0) = 0$ (1)
By substituting $y = 0$ we obtain $f(f(x) = f(0) - f(f(x))$ which implies that $f(f(x)) = 0$ pour tout $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ (2)
By substituting $x = 0$, we obtain $f(-y) = f(y)$ (3)

By switching the sign of $y$ we obtain :
$$f(f(x)+y) = f(-y) - f(f(x))$$
Which we can simplify with (3) and (2)
$$f(y+f(x)) = f(y)$$
We take any $f(x)$ that is non-zero. Let $k$ be this value of $x$ and $|f(k)| = a$. We have $f(y+a)=f(y)$ which means f(y+a) has a period of $a = |f(k)| $

Comment: Well, if it is periodic with period $P$ then the  bound on $|f(n)|$ is $\max (|f(0)|,|f(1)|, \cdots, |f(P-1)|)$.  But it's not obvious (to me at least) that it is periodic.  Perhaps you could edit your post to include your proof of that claim.

Comment: Of course. My proof was done in french so I will add it and edit it in the meantime.

Comment: Yes, your argument looks good.  And, as I explained in my first comment, periodicity instantly implies that the function is bounded.

Comment: So the bound on $|f(x)|$ here is $max(|f(0)|,|f(1)|,⋯,|f(a−1)|)$? It makes more sense, I forgot the function was defined on $\mathbb Z$. Would it have been differently if the function was defined on $\mathbb R$? (I was thinking about fuctions like tan which made me hesitant to call it bounded)

Comment: Well, $\tan (x)$ might be a poor example since it is not defined everywhere.  Take an example like:  $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational and $f\left(\frac pq\right)=q$ if $x$ is rational.  That's periodic with period $1$, it's defined everywhere, but it is not bounded.

Comment: To be clear:  for your situation, one might be able to prove more.  I have no idea if there is an unbounded function on the reals which satisfies your equation.  It might well be that your equation implies that the function is constant, I don't know.

Comment: Or briefly, if $f$ is periodic with period $P$, then its image is finite with at most $P$ elements, and every finite set is bounded.